# Scheme read specific data from file

Tags: matlab, scheme

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
1 17.3  
2 18.2  
3 18.6
```

I would like to make a variable (for example `temp`) which would store store first value (`17.3`). I would then compare this value with something else (`< temp 20`). Next step would be to store second value in `temp` (`18.2`), so I could again compare values.

Any help would be appreciated!

In Matlab it would look like this:

```
A=importdata(...)  
i=0;  
while i<length(temp) do  
 temp=A(i,2)  
 i=i+1;  
 if temp < 20  
    ...  
 end  
end
```

Comment: What scheme code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to skin this cat in R6RS:

1. You can use [read](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_816). `read` will read any Scheme datum so since these are all numbers `read` will read the next number.
2. You can make your own parser. You [read one char at a time](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_808) and when you hit a space or linefeed you take the list of chars you have though [list->string](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_714) to get string and then [string->number](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_584) This can also be done in two parts [reading lines](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_706) then parsing each line or do a [slurp](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_704) first then process the string.